# How can I convert latitude & longitude into north,south,east,west. if its possible In javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
let latitude: = 36.6839559;
let longitude = 3.6217802;
```

---

This API Requires north, south, east, west Parameters

---

```
const API = `http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=${north}south=${south}&east=${east}&west=${west}&lang=de&username=demo`;
```

Answer (score 4):

If `longitude < 0` then `West`, else `East`.

If `latitude < 0` then `South`, else `North`.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to answer the question. Looking at the API, it needs a bounding box. All of the north,south,east and west parameters are mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems like this api uses bounding box. With north, east, south and west being the corners of the box. And contrary to the other answers, just outputting the coordinates won't work. You need all of the bounding coordinates.

So to convert the coordinates to north, east etc we should add or subtract a kilometer (This is close enough). That is calculated in the function `kmInDegree(lat,long)`. The calculations are done based on the functions found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_latitude) .

So if we take the Beni Amrane, Algeria (36.68395,3.6217802) and add and subtract the right values we get this bounding box:

[image: example of bounding box]

If we then pass those values to the url we get the following output

```js
const API = 'http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=36.69395&south=36.67395&east=3.6324802&west=3.6104802&lang=de&username=demo';

//Result of the api call above
{
    "geonames": [
        {
            "lng": 3.616667,
            "geonameId": 2507983,
            "countrycode": "DZ",
            "name": "’Aïn N’Sara",
            "fclName": "city, village,...",
            "toponymName": "’Aïn N’Sara",
            "fcodeName": "populated place",
            "wikipedia": "",
            "lat": 36.683333,
            "fcl": "P",
            "population": 0,
            "fcode": "PPL"
        }
    ]
}
```

One can automate this process with the following function:

```js
function getBox(lat, long) {
  //calculate the offset of 1km at a certain coordinate
  const dist = kmInDegree(lat, long)
  //calculate the bounds and make an object of them
  let bounds = {
    north: lat + dist.lat,
    south: lat - dist.lat,
    east: long + dist.long,
    west: long - dist.long
  };
  return bounds;
}

//See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_latitude
function kmInDegree(lat, long) {
  const pi = Math.PI;
  const eSq = 0.00669437999014;
  const a = 6378137.0; //equatorial radius in metres
  lat = lat * pi / 180; //convert to radians
  long = long * pi / 180; //convert radians

  //I won't try to explain the calculations. All i know is that they are correct with the examples on wikipedia (see url above)
  const latLength = (pi * a * (1 - eSq)) / (180 * Math.pow((1 - eSq * Math.pow(Math.sin(lat), 2)), 3 / 2));

  const longLength = (pi * a * Math.cos(long)) / (180 * Math.sqrt((1 - (eSq * Math.pow(Math.sin(long), 2)))));

  //If you want a greater offset, say 5km then change 1000 into 5000
  return {
    lat: 1000 / latLength,
    long: 1000 / longLength
  };
}

//Just for demonstration purposes only. 
window.onload = function() {
  //get the box from the coordinates
  let box = getBox(36.68395, 3.6217802);

  //create the API URL
  const API = `http:\/\/api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=${box.north}&south=${box.south}&east=${box.east}&west=${box.west}&lang=de&username=demo`;

  console.log(API);
}
```

Hope this helps! If not, please comment

Comment: Be careful the distance covered by a degree of longitude varies depending on the latitude: at the poles its zero, at the equator around 11km as you mention. See https://www.johndcook.com/how_big_is_a_degree.html  So this method would give a smaller area near the poles. A bit of trigonometry (see perhaps "distance" function in source of that page) could probably compensate for this, such that the "box" (/sphere surface segment, esp near poles) is of (roughly) equal area irrespective of latitude.

Comment: @phhu yes I am aware of that however did not think it would matter too much for this application. Will add it later probably

Comment: Thanks for updating and the math!

Comment: @Chiel could you please do it in dart ?

Comment: @PannamT im not familiar with dart. However, it should be relatively easy to do